# How do I modify an iframe using CGI in Perl?

Tags: html, perl, iframe, cgi

So I have figured out how to "create" an iFrame using cgi, but I have no idea how to manipulate it (i.e. change size, change source, disable scrolling, etc). This is what I have written in Perl:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use CGI;

    my $page = new CGI;


    print $page->header;
    print $page->start_html;
    print $page->iframe("http://www.nasa.gov/");
    print $page->end_html;
```

But here is the HTML I receive:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US"><head><title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head><body><iframe>http://www.nasa.gov/</iframe></body></html>
```

Of course, when adding the source and size attributes, the info must go inside of the > symbol, like so:

```
<iframe src="http://www.nasa.gov/"> Enter Text Here </iframe>
```

Instead, CGI closes the iframe header, like so:

```
<iframe>http://www.nasa.gov/</iframe>
```

How am I supposed to modify the iframe in this case? Can it be done?

Comment: Why don't you just print out your html as you need it? Meaning print "<iframe src='yoursite.gov'></iframe>"

Comment: I believe I tried that before and got a 500 internal error in return. I will give it another shot, though.

Comment: I must have done something wrong before. This is my first experience with CGI and Perl. Works great now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
 print $page->iframe({src => "http://www.nasa.gov/"}, "");
```

You need to put the address into the `src` attribute, not into the `iframe` content (which is fallback content for browsers that do not support the element—a largely theoretical feature).